# Angular/TypeScript: Can't resolve all parameters when setting constructor property

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to import this fork of [mark.js](https://github.com/Gijsjan/mark.js) with the import statement,

```
import { Mark } from 'mark.ts'
```

When I attempt to set the constructor property,

```
constructor(private mark: Mark) { }
```

I get the error,

> Can't resolve all parameters...

My understanding of TypeScript is very limited, and I assume this is some kind of issue with the import statement, so I haven't included any other code. Let me know if it's necessary.

Comment: Doing that destroys the module resolution. "mark.ts" is the actual module name.

Comment: Okay, sorry. I'll be quiet now :D

Comment: Yeah, I just tried to rename the module directory, but that didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Import { Mark } from 'mark.ts' change capital I to a small 'i' like

   ```
   import { Mark } from 'mark.ts'
   ```
2. You can inject into constructor only Angular services annotated with @Injectable or Parents components or Angular OpaqueToken tokens.
3. You also can create a custom class, instantiate the object using new and pass it into a constructor of another object but you will do it manually not via Angular DI system.

Comment: The capital "I" in "Import" was actually a typo in my question. As for the rest, thanks for clarifying. I think I actually knew 2 at one point, but it seems to have left my head.